# Trouble Getting Div Elements Lined Up Correctly

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4, widget

Goal: Get the Ko-Fi Button Widget aligned so it does not cover up the privacy policy link, and is instead neatly placed right beside it. If I can do that, then I can do it for all other buttons/links in the footer bar I add in the future.

What I have tried:

1. Placing the Ko-Fi Code in its own div.
2. Nesting a div with the Ko-Fi Code in the container div
3. Placing the Ko-Fi Code in the container div.

What I currently have/my code:

```html
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - APixelADay - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            <script src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/scripts/overlay-widget.js'></script>
            <script>
                kofiWidgetOverlay.draw('knightshade07', {
                    'type': 'floating-chat',
                    'floating-chat.donateButton.text': 'Support me',
                    'floating-chat.donateButton.background-color': '#00b9fe',
                    'floating-chat.donateButton.text-color': '#fff'
                });
            </script>
        </div>   
    </footer>
```

What it visually looks like on the webpage:
[image]

What I want it to look like:
[image]

UPDATE: After a suggestion from dale landry, I did try moving elements around using CSS, but it did not work. Right now, I'm just trying to figure out how to get elements to display horizontally instead of vertically.

What I have now:

```html
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - APixelADay - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

What it visually looks like:
[image]

My footer CSS in the CSS folder (The CSS was made by Visual Studio itself,not me):

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

Comment: Have you tried placing any CSS on that footer? Perhaps a flex display with justify-content to see if it has any affect on the a tag. Maybe somthing like `.footer{ display: flex; justify-content: space-between; } .footer a { padding-right: 2rem; }` ?

Comment: Tried what you suggested, did not work.

Comment: Do you know how to use the inspector in your dev tools? Open the dev tools and see if you can place any kind of CSS on the element to manipulate it in any way, worth a try... Just look up whatever browser you;re using like *firefox how to use dev tools*

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging around on the Ko-Fi Website, and I found this:
https://help.ko-fi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018381678-Ko-fi-Donation-Widget

[image]

Unfortunately, it looks like you cannot do this at this point in time, but if that ever changes,then I can refer back to this question for help. If I am wrong about this however, do let me know!

UPDATE: So, in Bootstrap, there are these little things called list-groups. I added one to my project from the list group docs(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/):

```html
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://storage.ko-fi.com/cdn/widget/Widget_2.js'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript'>kofiwidget2.init('Support Me on Ko-fi', '#29abe0', 'A0A1571WM'); kofiwidget2.draw();</script> </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">&copy; 2020 - APixelADay - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

With the ul class being

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
```

And this is what I got:
[image]

Problem Solved.